# Android SDK Manager doesn't work: Download interrupted: "Tag mismatch"

Tags: android, sdk

I'm getting started on android developing. I've "played" a little bit with eclipse and now I'm trying some online examples dealing with streaming.

The thing is it seems I don't have the packages installed as, while debugging, I got the following error message: `Source not found`.

So, I tried to get the packages going to the SDK manager, selecting them and clicking `Install`.

And my problem is the following: I can't install them and don't know why.

Answer (score 11):

For me it was all about the Internet connection. Running wifi over 5Ghz/ac was too fast(!?) and the "tag mismatch"-problem was gone when connected through 2.4Ghz.

The same problem and solution applied when installing some new gradle dependencies in Android Studio.

Comment: This just solved my problem. How did you even figure this out? And any idea why it would be an issue that the connection is 'too fast'? I'm so confused (but happy).

Comment: I'm still getting this issue 10 months later, it's driving me up the wall :( 
Moving to my 2.4ghz network fixes it, but how the heck does this fix it??

Comment: Just tried this "solution" switching from 5Ghz ac to 2.4Ghz n and suprisingly it works now. WTF?

Comment: Welp 2 days of messing with my newly installed windows 10 configuration and it turns out to be this problem 2 days before 2020. GJ on this

Comment: Still happening... in 2023... Window 11 + SDD NVMe + 5ghz = nightmare.

Answer (score 10):

The "tag mismatch" error has to do with SSL and security certificates. While I don't know why the SSL is having a problem, in Android SDK manager you can skip using SSL encryption at all by clicking on tools >> options >> and check the box for "force https:// sources to be fetched using http://".

I was able to download the packages that way.

Answer (score 3):

When facing this error, I manage to complete the download using the menu in SDK Manager

Tools > Options > Manifest Cache > Clear Cache

Answer (score 2):

I got same error:
`Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image: Tag mismatch!.`

It happens when I use https with unstable networking (wifi).
Using `--no_https` option helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I also always have this problem, one thing that has worked for me so far is slowing down my download by running some other download that would consume bandwidth. Whenever I simultaneously download, it works fine; it's weird; I can't explain why

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was Configure -> SDK Manager -> Tools -> Web browser. I changed default browser to Chrome. Firefox had some problems.

Comment: What does the browser firefox or chrome have to do with the android sdk updates online and the download is interrupted?
Android sdk does not use any browser to upgrade, which is done internally to the product. What happens is that the server can not keep the connection and is always interrupted. Of course the faster the connection to the internet, the better the download and the chances of an outage will be lower.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the most recent android version.

here is the step by step directions of how to install SDK:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt

How to add more packages:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

The download progress is shown at the bottom of the SDK Manager window. Do not exit the SDK Manager or it will cancel the download.

Let me know if this is still not helping you.....